# Scifi novel about obese guy who remotely controlled a flying device and who had a robotic lover

Tags: story-identification, novel

This was a scifi novel where the main character of the book is a morbidly obese man who is unable to leave his house due to his size. He purchased a robot lover for sexual pleasure.

To satisfy his curiosity about the outside world, the man uses a flying device to explore the land from the safety of his own home.

The setting is a divided world, where on higher level people live in technologically superior life with robots, drones etc, while beneath live poor people in ruins.

Main character lives in his flat in the high realm and uses a flying remotely controlled drone to observe the lower level.

But once he was detected by some kind of underground rebels. In the end he has to leave his house.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: For example; What is his name? What is the setting (futuristic, I assume)? Was there any other future-tech mentioned? Was this a book for adults (with sex and explicit descriptions) or more aimed at juniors? What else happens in the book? Is there an inciting incident that gets the story going or is is just a description of his sad life?

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/50262048-before-and-after? Morbidly obese character uses drone to walk his dog at one point

Comment: Can't remember any more details, sory. Combination of overweighted main character, remotely-controlled drone and a robotic sex doll must be a unique combination.

Comment: I'm sure you can remember some more details; Did the book have any pictures? Was it written in English? When did you read it? What was on the cover? Was the sex doll/drone a major feature of the plotline or just something mentioned in passing? Remember that any details, no matter how small could be the key to finding it

Comment: @You've added a bounty to this one. Now is a good time to dig deep and come up with some extra details for us. Can you remember any specific words or phrases from the book? Was he described literally as "obese" or did they use another expression? How had he become housebound? Did he have any friends or family who were checking on him? How did the device fly (jets, rockets, quadcopter, anti-grav)? When did you read this? Was it part of a series or a stand-alone? Was the author male or female?